# What are gvim ~ files?

Tags: vim, gvim

Why is it when I create/save my file (say, filename is 'xyz.sql'), gvim saves another file which it calls 'xyz.sql~' in the same directory?  Can I delete this "extra" files or are they needed for some reason?  Even when I close gvim, they are still present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the vim [FAQ](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimfaq.html) [Section 7](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimfaq.html#7.1):

```
You have set the 'backup' option, so Vim creates a backup file when saving
the original file. You can stop Vim from creating the backup file, by
clearing the option:

    :set nobackup
```

Answer (score 1):

As another answer correctly says, these are backup files.  I wanted to just add that if you want to still have backup files, but don't want them to clutter your directories, you can use the `backupdir` option:

```
set backupdir=~/.backups,.
```

From the vim help:

List of directories for the backup file, separated with commas.

- The backup file will be created in the first directory in the list
        where this is possible.  The directory must exist, Vim will not
        create it for you.
- Empty means that no backup file will be created ('patchmode' is
        impossible!).  Writing may fail because of this.

Comment: that's a good feature as well, thanks @Jan Hlavacek